# how to send :id to service url of angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am new to angular 2.
can you guys help me out.

i have scenario like this,

user fetches complaint details by entering complaint id.

i have the url like this :

http://192.168.0.106:8000/app/complaint/complaintstatus/:id

this id we need to send to server.so that we can fetch the data.

by passing manually i am fetching the data

my code:

```
export class ComplaintService{
    private _url:string ="http://192.168.0.106:8000/app/complaint/complaintstatus"
    constructor(private _http:Http){}
    getCompliants(){
        return this._http.get(this._url).map((response:Response)=>response.json());
    }
}


export class ComplaintStatusComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _complaintService:ComplaintService) { }
  complaints={};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCompliants();
  }
  getComplaintDetails(complntId:any){

    console.log(complntId);
    this._complaintService.getCompliants().subscribe(data => this.complaints=data);
 }
 getCompliants():void{

 }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: thanks @sachilaranawaka want to send the id to server to fetch the record

Comment: is your id is `complntId`

Comment: yes. @sachilaranawaka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the id as argument to the `getCompliants` function and append it to the url

```
 getComplaintDetails(complntId:any){ 
    console.log(complntId);
    this._complaintService.getCompliants(complntId).subscribe(data => this.complaints=data);
 }

export class ComplaintService{
    private _url:string ="http://192.168.0.106:8000/app/complaint/complaintstatus"
    constructor(private _http:Http){}
    getCompliants(complntId){
        return this._http.get(this._url + '/:' + complntId).map((response:Response)=>response.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info @sachila ranawaka but facing the error here getComplaintDetails(complntId:any){

    console.log(complntId);
    this._complaintService.getCompliants().subscribe(data => this.complaints=data);
 }
 getCompliants():void{

 }
}

Comment: remove the `:any`

Comment: no use bro .getting the below error      /home/ajay/pcs-web/src/app/complaint-status/complaint-status.component.ts (22,5): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.)

Comment: this._complaintService.getCompliants().subscribe(data => this.complaints=data);

Comment: did you pass the `complntId` as parameter to `getCompliants`. like `this._complaintService.getCompliants(complntId).subscribe(data => this.complaints=data);`

Comment: Thanks @sachila ranawaka  removed ":"  this symbol it worked for  me

Comment: have one more question bro.the data is not displaying in my console but getting networks

Comment: you mean in browser network tab you can see the data

Comment: yes bro.i can able to see there.and my html is like this.<div class="col-md-6 panel panel-default">
  <p class="center"><strong>complaint status</strong></p>
  <form name="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="complntId" [(ngModel)]="complntId" placeholder="Registration Number" required>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-promary" (click)="getComplaintDetails(complntId)">Get Details</button>
  </form>
</div>

Comment: add console here and check `this._complaintService.getCompliants(complntId).subscribe(data => console.log(data));`

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking For angular 2 pass parameter in url please refer this link :
For that  you can code look like this for angular 2:

In your scenario you can use code for router look like this :

{
    path: 'home/promotiondetail',
    component: component name

}

and in your html side you can declare your router code look like this :

[routerLink]="['promotiondetail']" [queryParams]="{ id: {{id}} }"

You can also refer this URL :

[How to use questionmark in URl using angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999413/how-to-use-questionmark-in-url-using-angular-2)

Comment: i will try this by this weekend@Ravi

Comment: Ya, sure if any issue let me know.I would help you in any manner,

Comment: had one question.if i click on button it should navigate to that path

Comment: yes. It should be navigate that to particular location. for example in that scenario it should be navigate that path example : http://localhost:50465/promotion?id=132

Comment: i added one question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096308/angular-2-when-passing-id-in-url-its-showing-complntid-ts0000031

Comment: It means do you want to show id in url or don't want to show id in url?

Comment: then you should use router like this : [routerLink]="['/complainstatus', {{id}}]".  using this you should get this link : complaintstatus/id

Comment: user enters particular complaint id and he will submit.whenever user submit that it should navigate to the that url and display that.i have the button submit code like this. <button class="btn btn-promary" (click)="getComplaintDetails(complntId)">Get Details</button