# How to use questionmark in URl using angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I am new in Angular 2 
Here, shown code for router where my url would be display.
[Router Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKGWF.png)
Now, When I run that code the url look like this..

localhost:50465/promotion%3Fid%3D/51059

In that url display %3F instad of question mark(?) and %3D instead of equalto(=) .show how to get display my original url. my codelook like that.

I want to output like this :
http://localhost:50465/promotion?id=132

how can acheive this please help me.

please help me..!!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you're looking for how to decode an URI encoded string, right? If yes, what about using `decodeURIComponent(your_url_encoded_variable); ` ?

Comment: Yes, I am looking same but how to use decodeuri method in route path? how to implement in typescript file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your scenario you can use code for router look like this :

```
{       
    path: 'home/promotiondetail',        
    component: component name
}
```

and in your html side you can declare your router code look like this :

```
[routerLink]="['promotiondetail']" [queryParams]="{ id: {{id}} }"
```

show when you run this code you can get url look like this :

http://localhost:50465/promotion?id=132

Hope,this is useful. 
For more information use this link : https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html

Comment: @AJT_82,@Ravi Shah can you look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096308/angular-2-when-passing-id-in-url-its-showing-complntid-ts0000031