# Angular 2 when passing id in url it's showing ?complntId=TS0000031

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

have a scenario,if user enters one number and submit it should navigate to that id and display the details.

when i navigate url,it's showing something like this

**complaintstatus/TS0000031?complntId=TS0000031**

Detail view code:

```
export class ComplaintDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    id:number;
    private sub:any;
    complntId : any;
    constructor(private ComponentService:ComplaintService,private route:ActivatedRoute){

    }
    ngOnInit() {

   this.sub= this.route.params.subscribe((params:Params)=>{
        this.ComponentService.getCompliants(params['complntId'])
    });
    console.log(this.sub);

  }
```

user enters id code :

```
export class ComplaintStatusComponent {

    constructor(private router:Router){}
getComplaintDetails(complntId){
  this.router.navigate(['/complaintstatus', complntId]);
}  

}
```

and one more question,how can i send user enter id to another component.

and service code:

```
export class ComplaintService{
    private _url:string ="http://192.168.0.106:8000/app/complaint/complaintstatus"
    constructor(private _http:Http){}
    getCompliants(complntId){
        return this._http.get(this._url + '/' + complntId).map((response:Response)=>response.json());

    }
}
```

routing Module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path:'complaintregistration',component:ComplaintRegistartionComponent},
    {path:'complaintstatus',component:ComplaintStatusComponent},
    {path:'complaintstatus/:complntId',component:ComplaintDetailComponent}
];
```

Comment: if you need to send the id to another component use a service to send info across components , or you can use ngrx store

Comment: You pinged me, so here I am :D The code looks pretty good to me... have you console logged `compIntId` before passing it as a param?

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks . yes it is working and printing whatever id submitting,it is printing in the console

Comment: Hmm... okay well what does that parameter look like when console logging, just to get some idea where this odd url is coming from.

Comment: @AJT_82 just the id is printing.TS0000031

Comment: @Ajay, could you show the routing module?

Comment: @AJT_82 code updated.You can have look

Comment: @Ajay Hmm... this seems strange I can't really see any obvious error here... :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145182/discussion-between-ajay-and-ajt-82).

Comment: @Ajay Could I test this locally, do you have github or something?

Comment: @AJT_82 no github.you can do it with the above information

Comment: @Ajay I'm not here to do all the work ;) Please then create a working Plunker, that I can debug :)

Comment: @AJT_82 unable to produce the plunker

Comment: unable to reproduce the issue, or produce the plunker? Well if I can, then you should be able too ;) I took a stab at your code yesterday, based on the code you have presented and created a plunker, and I couldn't reproduce the issue, meaning the code worked fine for me. Just had to add a `redirectTo` in routing: `{path: '', redirectTo: '/whateverComponentYouWant',pathMatch: 'full'},` (but that shouldn't be an issue with your current problem). One thought, how does your selectors look in the components?

Comment: ...still I had to do some "guessing" on how your code looks like, so you might have some issues somewhere, that's why I want you to recreate the issue in a plunker, so that we can find where the error is...

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks for the info.am trying to create new application and just copy all the stuff to there i will check it.

Comment: @AJT_82 i tried with pathMatch no use

Comment: Yes as I said, that shouldn't be the cause of your problem. I asked before, how does your selectors look for your components?

Comment: @AJT_82 i am trying to create plunker i will update you soon.

Comment: @AJT_82 can you send your email,so that i will send

Comment: @AJT_82 shared it in drive can you have a look

Comment: @AJT_82 have you seen that

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it... and tried it, worked fine for me. Try and reinstalling node modules and restarting your project. There is something funky going on there, your code is completely correct tho :) http://imgur.com/a/71XKG

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks for your time.and i just install npm right?

Comment: Yeah, remove the node_modules folder from your project and run npm install after that. Hope you can solve this problem, sometimes just restarting everything magically solves a problem :D Hope that is the case! If not, I'm really sorry I can't really help any further :(

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks for your help